# MKLocalSearchCompleter results missing

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I encountered a problem, I want to search worldwide place, i am use MKLocalSearchCompleter, but search result only show china, for example i am search "纽约", but did not show results about NewYork，my code is as follows：

```
fileprivate var completer = MKLocalSearchCompleter()
completer.delegate = self
self.completer.queryFragment = "纽约"
```

so, is missing setting property?
thanks.

Comment: This seems to be a problem with Apple's map service. I have [reported](https://github.com/feedback-assistant/reports/issues/462) it to them. I recommend you do the same. The more reports, the more likely they will look into it.